# Create multiple field indexes with different types on postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, index-tuning

I have the following query on an 18M records table (which grows daily by 5k):

```
SELECT * from marketing 
where start_time < '2017-02-19 08:00:00' 
AND NOT name LIKE '%MyWorld%' 
AND product = 'Product2'
```

I am using **postgres 9.3.1**

This is a report table that is being updated in an offline process, but I need to return the results from the report online, quickly.

I thought to use [gin index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin.html), however, since my query filters 3 columns, I believe that I need a composite index

```
CREATE INDEX marketing_name_start_date_product_gin_trgm_idx ON tbl USING gist 
(name, start_date, product gin_trgm_ops);
```

However this seems like a waste for me to create a gin index for columns which don't use like in queries.

What do you suggest? What is the best approach?

Comment: If you use `LIKE %xxxx%` with column `name`, you should have the `gin_trgm_ops` with that column, instead of `product`. Assuming all selectivities being equal (which is a rather naïve assumption), I'd order *product*, where you look for a *precise* value (= operator), and a single one; then *start_time*, then *name*. Suggestion from @Evan to try different combinations (more or less columns) and column-orders is the best one, in any case.

Comment: do you mean: 
CREATE INDEX marketing_name_start_date_product_gin_trgm_idx ON tbl USING gist 
(name  gin_trgm_ops, start_date, product);

Comment: Yes. But you either use *everything GIN* (USING gin and gin_trgm_ops) or *everything GiST* (USING gist and gist_trgm_ops).

Comment: that means that all of the columns will be indexes with gin? wouldn't it affect performance?

Comment: No, you don't need all indexes to be gin. But is you have one index `USING gist` then the trigram operators to use must be `gist_trgrm_ops` (not `gin_trgrm_ops`). If, instead of a GIN index, then you must write `USING gin`. You're mixing `gin` and `gist` in the create index sentence; and this isn't likely to (properly) work.  Check [Rextester](http://rextester.com/VWE31474)

Comment: Thanks so you basically saying that I don't need one composite index with all 3 fields but rather 2 indexes: CREATE INDEX marketing_name_gin_trgm_idx ON tbl USING gin 
( name gin_trgrm_ops) and CREATE INDEX marketing_product_start_date_index
  ON marketing
  USING btree
  (product, report_datetime_start); ?

Comment: Try having them separate and try combining them. It depends a lot on your specific case, the kind of queries you make, and the data you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be impossible for us to assist in with the information provided. However, rest assured 18M is not much. Baseline questions include,

- Ignoring the LIKE condition, what is the selectivity that can be provided on start_time and product?
- Do you ever select on start_time, and name, *without* product?
- When you have a btree on (start_time, product), and a gin/gist tgrm index on name, how much times does the query take?
- When you create the index described, how much time does the query take?

Take a look at the plans required by both. I would do these tests on a snap shot of the table so it's fair (or two snapshots with only the indexes mentioned)

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT * FROM marketing
```

Comment: Thanks.
1. I am not sure that I understood the first question about start_time
2. no, only with it
3. I can check it, but I thought that an index can work out ONLY if all fields of the query are in the same index

Comment: You're wondering about, `WHERE start_time < '2017-02-19 08:00:00' 
AND NOT name LIKE '%MyWorld%' 
AND product = 'Product2'`, how many results does that return. How many results does `where start_time < '2017-02-19 08:00:00' 
AND product = 'Product2'` return?

Comment: the first one returns about 47k results, the second done returns about 50k results

Answer (score 1):

Your text search is not a `LIKE` query, it is a `NOT LIKE` query.  A gin_trgm_ops index is not going to help a `NOT LIKE` query.  And a gist_trgm_ops is very unlikely to help, either.

Your best bet is probably to make in an index on `(product, start_time_or_date, name)`.  That will let you scan only the index entries which match both the equality and inequality, and apply a filter for the `NOT LIKE` right in the index without visiting the table.